# ArryIndexOutOfBoundsException in counter/odd even sorter

Tags: counter, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public class CounterAndSorter
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        int oddSum = 0;
        int evenSum = 0;

        while(counter <= 25)
        {
            if(counter % 2 > 0)
            {
                oddSum += counter;
            }
            else
            {
                evenSum += counter;
            }

            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println("The sum of the even integers is " + evenSum);
        System.out.println("The sum of the odd integers is " + oddSum);
    }
}
```

I have recently started java and am trying to write a program to generate 100 random integers, then sort them into even and odds and display them via arrays. I can compile the above code but am unable to execute it. I continually receive a Out Of Bounds Exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can compile and run this without a problem, the output is this: "The sum of the even integers is 156  
The sum of the odd integers is 169".  Can you paste the stack trace of the OOB exception?  That would help us narrow it down.

Comment: FYI - There's nothing yet being stored in arrays in this code.  You're just adding to oddSum or evenSum with every integer... which are being incremented by 1 and not randomly generated.

Comment: sorry, still getting used to this site, it changed to another program somehow...